# Screaming Frog marking duplicate on noindex pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, noindex, screaming-frog

Screaming Frog is detecting as duplicate all login pages of my site despite I have the directive `robots`-`noindex`.

Do I have a problem on my site, or is just a false positive from Screaming Frog?

It detects multiple login pages, because I have a `returnUrl` parameter.

Comment: Why do you have multiple login pages?  It it just that you have a parameter on the page that says where to go back to after logging in?  You might just want to disallow your login page in robots.txt instead of using a noindex tag.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it is. Is better to disallow it that having it with no index?

Comment: Many bots are going to crawl every variation of that parameter that they find.  There isn't any value in allowing search engine bots do all that crawling it just to find out they can't index it.